# How to determine the support (bounds) of a cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Suppose that *X* is uniformly distributed on [0,2]. Suppose that *Y* = X$^3$

Find the probability density function for *Y* and state the support for *Y*.

I know the CDF will be G(y) = P(*Y* $\le$ *y*) = P(X$^3$ $\le$ *y*) = P(*x* $\le$ y$^{1/3}$) =

$$\int_0^{ \infty}\dfrac{1}{2}dx$$

But I'm not sure how to determine what the support (bounds) are actually supposed to be for this particular example, or for any other CDF problem.

Answer (score 1):

The support of $X$ is $[0,2].$ As $X$ takes values in its support
$Y = X^3$ takes values in $[0, 2^3] = [0, 8],$ which is therefore
the support of $Y.$  Notice that the CDF of $X$ is 
$F(x) = P(X \leq x) = \int_0^x 1/2\,dx = x/2,$ for $x \in [0,2].$

Then, your expression for the CDF of $Y$ should read:
$$G(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(X^3 \leq y) = P(X \leq y^{1/3})
= y^{1/3}/2,$$
for $y \in [0,8].$ Notice that $G(0) = 0$ and $G(8) = 1,$
so that the CDF of $Y$ is continuous.