# How can one expand the support of a cumulative distribution function (CDF)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have experimental data confined to a specific interval, allowing us to compute a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF). Recognizing potential biases within the data and understanding the need to extend the interval beyond the observed data, the question arises: Is it possible to adjust the support and refine the existing CDF (computed within the experimental data's interval)?

I came across a post on this website ([How to determine the support (bounds) of a cumulative distribution function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260006/how-to-determine-the-support-bounds-of-a-cumulative-distribution-function)), but unfortunately, it did not provide the assistance I needed.

It's possible that expanding the support analytically may not be feasible as I desire. Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $F(x) = x^{0.5}$ on the interval $[0.1, 0.5]$ isn't a CDF. Your question is unclear.

Comment: It was solely an example. Allow me to disagree; the question isn't unclear. The inquiry is as follows: With experimental data confined to an interval we can compute a CDF. Supposing we recognize that the data might be biased and that the interval extends beyond the observed data, is it feasible to adjust the support and refine the existing CDF?

This question appears quite straightforward to me. The vote to close it is frankly unwise and impedes one's ability to progress and learn.

Comment: the phrasing of your question in your comment is far clearer than the question body. I encourage you to update the question to reflect that.

Comment: I've revised the question. I hope it now aligns better with your (and the forum) preferences.

Comment: How do you want to refine the cdf? Do you have an application-deriven transformation for this purpose?

Comment: A good way to extend the CDF is having a parametric model from the data. In this case, you posit the distribution $F$ from which your data comes, parametrised by $\theta$, say. You may estimate $\theta$ and this will give you an estimate of the full cdf